# Samsung duos remove and re-insert battery makes battery life sudden drop

Tags: battery, battery-life, samsung

I have a samsung duos i9082 without root.
the battery life drop 10% - 50% when remove and reinsert the battery.

So my question is.
is this a battery problem or devices or software?

Does replace a new battery fix this issue?

**update question**

The first drop is remove and re-insert battery.
The second drop is from 15% - 0% (less than 5mins)
48% usage by screen.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my experience as a phone technician, that kind of issue is most often the battery. There will usually be a 0-2% drop after a bat pull because of the required power for boot up. Does the battery have any sort of swelling to it? If so then it's undoubtedly the battery.

Comment: no swelling. it drops extremely fast not just 0-2%. mostly 10 - 20%.

Comment: From your observation, does the phone charge faster than it used to? Often times a phone will charge faster as the life of the battery diminishes

Comment: No, charge speed like normal.
I updated my question with picture. Please check it

Comment: I strongly believe it's the battery. Erratic readings like that tell me the battery is going bad. It reminds me of a " hollow charge " where it states its at a certain percentage but in reality its much lower. The only way to be certain is to ; 1. Factory reset phone after backing up info then experiment. However a battery replacement will likely solve this.

Comment: Ok. Will get a new battery and try

Comment: Replaced a new battery. Same issue :(

Comment: That is odd. Sorry that didn't work. If it's your phone misreading the batteries charge it may need to be recalibrated. With root this can be achieved via various apps. Without root I've seen a factory reset fix issues similar to this.it's very rare though. If that doesn't work I'm at a loss.

Comment: Factory reset tried before   not work. Will try root later

Comment: rooted + battery calibration not work as well. I notice something now. either new or old battery the 100% - 85%  and 15% - 0% are not usable. the battery life sudden drop at that area.

Comment: Its too bad there isnt another duos to test this with. Has samsung provided a reflash image of this device? I would assume so. If so, that may be an option as its much more thorough than a traditional factory reset. I cant imagine why two batteries are reacting the same way. When the battery is in the phone, is the drain normal vs how it was before these issues occurred? Also is the device older or newer